# Who are the four heroes who can face Elder Centipede according to Gyoro Gyoro?

Tags: one-punch-man

In the One Punch Man manga Phoenix Man mentions that according to Gyoro Gyoro only 4 heroes can face Elder Centypede. I dont know if I'm missing a panel or something but he mentions only 2, Blast and King. Who are the other 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The four heroes that can defeat Elder Centipede according to Gyoro Gyoro:

- The Tornado of Terror
- Metal Knight
- King
- Blast

He said it in Chapter 84: Escalation.

Pages that he said it:

> [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]